# Minic slider links are not clickable in IE9-IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, hyperlink, module, slider, prestashop-1.5

The minic slider links are not working in IE9-IE10. We deinstalled the module and reinstalled a newer version and an older verison of the module. With both versions the links still did not work. We tried to fix the problem with CSS, by setting the z-index higher or use diffrent display commands. The Prestashop version is 1.5.6.2. Thanks in advance.

http://kinesiotape24.ch/